# Replacing an item of a list by the item of another list if the condition matches

Tags: python

Suppose I have 2 lists as below. I am comparing items of both the lists and if the 1st item of  list1 exists in the item of list2 then replace the item of list1 by the matched item of list2 and then delete that item from list2. Then it should move to the 2nd item of list1 and so on. I have the following code which is incorrect but I can't figure out the way. The number of items in both the lists may not be the same.

```
list1 = ["abc", "abc", "abc", "xyz", "xyz"]
list2= ["abc123", "abc456", "abc000", "xyz111"]

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i in j:
            i.replace(i, j)
            list2.remove(j)
            continue
        else:
            continue
```

The result should be as:

```
list1 = ["abc123", "abc456", "abc000", "xyz111", "xyz"]
```

Comment: You are removing from `list2` while you are looping through it. That will always cause problems. Assuming your method is otherwise correct, you can either loop through it backwards or make a copy of it and loop through that.

Comment: Also, the entire `continue-else-continue` construction appears quite unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`[i]zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) for this:

```
from itertools import izip_longest # zip_longest for 3.x

list1 = [b if a in b else a 
         for a, b in izip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue="")]
list2 = [a for a in list2 if a not in list1]
```

This keeps the indexing consistent between the two lists during the first step (unlike `remove`), then clears out `list2` afterwards.

Comment: Nice answer. The only thing to change is `b.startswith(a)` needs to be `a in b`. The string `b` doesn't have to start with `a` it just has to contain it.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for i in list1`, you are getting the elements of the list, not the position of the list.

```
>>> for i in list1:
...    print(type(i))
... 
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

To work correctly you should do something like this down here and change the list inplace

```
>>> for i in range(len(list1)):
...    print(i)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
>>> list1 = ["abc", "abc", "abc", "xyz", "xyz"]
>>> list2= ["abc123", "abc456", "abc000", "xyz111"]
>>>
>>> [ list2[i] if i < len(list2) and list2[i].startswith(elem) 
...   else elem
...   for i, elem in enumerate(list1)]
```

#### Output:

```
['abc123', 'abc456', 'abc000', 'xyz111', 'xyz']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code:

```
>>> for list in list1:
...     for a in list2:
...         if list in a:
...             list1[list1.index(list)] = a
...             del list2[list2.index(a)]
... 
>>> 
>>> print list1
['abc123', 'abc000', 'abc456', 'xyz111', 'xyz']
>>> print list2
[]
>>>
```